# Pretty toc : titlecontents formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am trying to format my \chapter and \section titles in the table of contents in order to reach this aspect :

[image]

I am trying to use titlecontents in order to do this. Here is my code and the result :

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{librecaslon}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
              [0em]
              {\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont \filcenter \addvspace{30pt}}%
              {PARTIE \thecontentslabel \\\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\\}%
              {1em}%
              {}%
\titlecontents{section}
              [0em]
              {\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont \addvspace{30pt}}%
              {Chapitre \thecontentslabel \hspace{1cm}}%
              {}%
              {\enspace \contentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Conditions d'application}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to improve this ?

- How to add space between "Partie 1", the line, and between the line and "Introduction" ?
- How to have a different format for "Chapitre 1" and "Conditions d'application" ?
- How to have "Conditions d'application" on two lines ?
- How to get the page number to the correct position ?

Thank you all for your help !

---

EDIT : thank you @Bernard for your answer. Using this code, I have split my toc in two columns :

```
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
```

As you can see, \titlecontents for \part is not working well. And it seems that page numbers are not well-positioned in this case (look at \subsubsection level, called "Section 1" and "Section 2"). Here is my code (I have tried using \sloppy, it is much better but not perfect) :

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{librecaslon}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{supertabular}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}

% **************************
% **************************
% /part formatting
% **************************
% **************************

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}


% **************************
% Fonction pour faire les deux traits encadrant les pages Livre et Partie.
% **************************

\newcommand\framethispage[1][1cm]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.2pt]
    \draw([xshift=(#1),yshift=(-#1)]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=(#1),yshift=(#1)+2mm]current page.south west);%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.2pt]
    \draw([xshift=(#1),yshift=(-#1)]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=(-#1)-2mm,yshift=(-#1)]current page.north east);%
}

% **************************
% Introduction générale --> \intropart
% **************************

\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

\newcommand{\intropart}[1]{
\pagebreak
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
    \thispagestyle{empty} \framethispage[2cm] \vspace{-12cm} \Huge \begin{center}
    \textbf{#1}
    \end{center} \pagebreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale} % table of contents line
  %\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Introduction générale}}{}
  \small

\else
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak
~
\newpage
\cleardoublepage
  \newpage \thispagestyle{empty} \framethispage[2cm] \vspace{-12cm} \Huge \begin{center} \textbf{#1} \end{center} \pagebreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Introduction générale} % table of contents line
  %\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Introduction générale}}{}
  \newpage
  \pagebreak
  \small
  ~
\fi
\thispagestyle{empty} \cleardoublepage
}

% **************************
% Introduction --> \introchap
% **************************

\newcommand{\introchapter}[1]{\begin{center}
    \textbf{\fontsize{16}{12} \selectfont #1} \vspace{3cm}
\end{center}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} % table of contents line

}


% **************************
% Livre 1 --> \part
% **************************

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\framethispage[2cm]
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
\else
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
\fi
{\parindent \z@ 
\interlinepenalty \@M
\normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\vspace{-9.5cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={anchor=base,inner sep=0pt}]
\node[my node] (center) {\fontsize{12}{12} \selectfont \frutL \text{Livre} \thepart};
\draw($(center.base)+(-1.9cm,-1ex)$)     -- ($(center.base)+(+1.9cm,-1ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\par\nobreak
\fi
\begin{center}
\fontsize{18}{12} \selectfont \acasR #2
\end{center}
\markboth{}{}\par}
\newpage
\@afterheading}
\makeatother


% **************************
% Titre
% **************************

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\begin{center}
    TABLE ANALYTIQUE
\end{center}

}

% **************************
% Deux colonnes
% **************************

\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

% **************************
% Mise en forme
% **************************

\titlecontents{part}
              [0em]
              {\Large\bfseries\filcenter \addvspace{15pt}}%
              {\qquad\textsf{\textsc{Livre}\enspace\thecontentslabel}\\[-1ex]\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\smallskip\\\qquad}%
              {1em}%
              {}%
\titlecontents{chapter}
              [0em]
              {\Large\bfseries\filcenter \addvspace{15pt}}%
              {\qquad\textsf{\textsc{Partie}\enspace\thecontentslabel}\\[-1ex]\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\smallskip\\\qquad}%
              {1em}%
              {}%
\titlecontents{section}
              [0em]
              {\Large\bfseries\filcenter \addvspace{15pt}}%
              {\qquad\textsf{\textsc{Titre}\enspace\thecontentslabel}\\[-1ex]\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\smallskip\\\qquad}%
              {1em}%
              {}%
\titlecontents{subsection}
              [0em]
              {\large\bfseries \addvspace{8pt}}%
              {\contentspush{\sffamily \textsc{Chapitre} \thecontentslabel \quad}}%
              {}%
              {\enspace\hfill\sffamily\mdseries\contentspage}%
\titlecontents{subsubsection}
              [0em]
              {\large\bfseries \addvspace{8pt}}%
              {\contentspush{\sffamily \textsc{Section} \thecontentslabel \quad}}%
              {}%
              {\enspace\hfill\sffamily\mdseries\contentspage}%
\titlecontents{subsubsubsection}
              [5pt]
              {\large\bfseries \addvspace{8pt}}%
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel \quad}}%
              {}%
              {\enspace\hfill\sffamily\mdseries\contentspage}%
\titlecontents{paragraph}
              [10pt]
              {\large \addvspace{8pt}}%
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel\text{.} \quad}}%
              {}%
              {\enspace\hfill\sffamily\mdseries\contentspage}%
\titlecontents{subparagraph}
              [20pt]
              {\large \addvspace{3pt}}%
              {\contentspush{\thecontentslabel\text{°} \quad}}%
              {}%
              {\enspace\hfill\sffamily\mdseries\contentspage}%
\begin{document}
\sloppy

\part{Part level not working}

\chapter{Pretty long title}

\section{Title test}

\section{Title test}

\subsection{Title test}

\subsubsection{Title tesssssssst}

\subsubsubsection{Title test}

\subparagraph{Title test}

\subparagraph{Title test}

\paragraph{Title test}

\subsubsubsection{Title test}

\subsubsection{Title test Title test}

\section{Title test}

\chapter{Title test}
\part{Part again}

\twocolumn
\twocolumntoc

\end{document}
```

Here is the result (look at "Section 1"):

[image]

Comment: So your chapters are parts, and your sections  chapters?  This is very confusing, semantically…

Comment: I know, I am really sorry about this. But \part is already "Livre"... But of course if someone has an answer with "Partie" as \part and "Chapitre" as \chapter, I will change to "Partie" as \chapter and "Chapitre" as \section myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this, though  I'm not sure I understand all of your requirements: what do you mean with  ‘different format’? I interpreted it as using a smallcaps sans font for ‘Chapitre  1’, so I had to use a sans font with small caps (TeX-Gyre Heros). As to the title on two lines, it is automatic if the title is too long. I used a longer title than yours to show how it can be done playing with contents margin. The \contentspush command was  added to have a *hang* format.

```
\documentclass[10pt ,twoside, french]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{librecaslon}
\usepackage[scale = 1.02]{tgheros}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin[1em]{4em}
\titlecontents{chapter}
              [0em]
              {\Large\bfseries\filcenter \addvspace{30pt}}%
              {\qquad\textsf{\textsc{Partie}\enspace\thecontentslabel}\\[-1ex]\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\smallskip\\\qquad}%
              {1em}%
              {}%
\titlecontents{section}
              [0em]
              {\large\bfseries \addvspace{30pt}}%
              {\contentspush{\sffamily \textsc{Chapitre} \thecontentslabel \quad}}%
              {}%
              {\enspace\hfill\sffamily\mdseries\contentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Conditions d'application, menues billevesées et autres fariboles}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

Here is the code you can use  to obtain the `\part` playout compatible whith your needs and the two-column table of contents:

```
 \titleformat{\part}[display]{%
 \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
\hskip20mm\rule[22mm]{0.5pt}{\dimexpr\paperheight-42mm}}%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\hskip20mm\rule[-20mm]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-42mm}{0.5pt}}}\filcenter}%
 {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont{\frutL Livre~\thepart}\\ \rule[2pt]{3.8cm}{0.5pt}}{20pt}{\fontsize{18}{12} \selectfont}

\titlecontents{part}
              [0em]
              {\Large\bfseries\filcenter \addvspace{15pt}}%
              {\qquad\textsf{\textsc{Livre}~thecontentslabel}\\[-1ex]\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\smallskip\\\qquad}%
              {1em}%
              {}%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have two remaining questions : - how can I have only "chapter 1" and not 1.1 ? And how to make this work with \part title ? Using the same code changing \chapter with \part does not seem to work. By the way, thank you, I didn't know about "fariboles" ;)

Comment: @Guliup: I don't have time at the moment, but I'll look at it later,  this evening.

Comment: Thank you very much! And if I may ask you an extra question, it seems that your code does not work with two-columns tables of contents. I have edited my initial question with some explanations (with ou without \sloppy).

Comment: Hello @Bernard, sorry to bother you again. Do you have any idea regarding this not-aligned page number? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Gulliup: Aligned how, exactly? The 3 is at the level of the second line of the title, but perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: if you look at my initial post, I have edited it with your code on a two-columns table of contents. On the screenshot I have uploaded, you can see that "Section 1 Title tessssst" has its page number not doing well. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Gulliup: I think this is due to TeX not being able to hyphen this word. Try  with `tessss\-sssst` to  propose a hyphenation, and perhaps also it is linked to the `\part` problem. This one is easy to solve: as latex displays \part in the toc in a non-standard way, to make `\titlecontents{\part}...` work, you have to load titlesec with the `[newparttoc]` option and redefine  the part formatting. Here is the code to do it  with the same result as the default formatting: `\titleformat{\part}[display]{\filcenter\bfseries}{\huge\partname~\Roman{part}}{20pt}{\Huge}`.

Comment: Thank you, it works... But it destroys my previous formatting of \part command using \makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{% ...
Is it the only way to do it ?

Comment: You mean the formatting of the part title in the text body, not in the toc?

Comment: Yes. I have previously formatted part title in the text body using \makeatletter \def\@part[#1]#2{% ... If I add \titleformat{\part}[display]{\filcenter\bfseries}{\huge\partname~\Roman{part}}{20pt}{\Huge} as you suggested, this formatting disappeared.

Comment: I've reproduced the default layout, but I'm sure what you've done it can be done with titlesec. I'll take a look a little later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106751/discussion-between-guliup-and-bernard).